# How is "닳고 닳다" used and what does it mean exactly?

Tags: meaning

I've found the following meanings for it in the Naver dictionay:

1. become oversophisticated
2. be too much a man of the world

In what situations would you use it it? How is it different from the meaning of
닳다? As far as I understand it's fairly negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Naver's online dictionary:

[닳다 -> Be worn out due to overuse (see 1)](https://ko.dict.naver.com/kokodict/#/entry/koko/7fe484c3569945448a0863de5ea69e18)

(eg from same page: 바지기 닳다: pants worn out from overuse)

[닳고 닳다: become knowledgeable about the ways of the world after seeing hardship](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/9ada9f8dabf54d5f9656215e73eed54f)
(eg from same page: 사람은 누구나 나이가 들면 세상일에 닳고 닳아서 순진함을 자꾸만 잃어버리게 된다.)

It is close to the meaning of hardships of life making someone more self centered or apathetic.